# Does the SharePoint list (office 365) have a capability to act as a slowly changing dimension?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssis, office365, sharepoint-online

Does the SharePoint list (office 365) have a capability to act as a slowly changing dimension like in SSIS? To avoid question like? Why not use SSIS? or Why use a SharePoint list to make it work like a slowly changing dimension?

Facts:
1. We don't have SSIS in my company, we only have office 365.
2. So my colleagues gather data manually and put it in a database, they call the excel sheet as database. They wanted me to create a SharePoint list and upload the first batch of the data and then update the list as the excel spreadsheet gets updated.

For example, the first data I copied and pasted from excel and then put it in a Sharepoint list. I have an excel sheet with a table

```
First Name    Last Name    Country          State

Michael       Smith        United States    Virginia
Michelle      Faris        United States    New Jersey
Jim           Siegle       United States    Boston
Anna          Harris       United States    Ohio
```

And then the excel sheet gets updated, Michelle Faris gets married, changes her lastname, Jim Siegle moves from Boston to Oregon.

```
First Name    Last Name    Country          State

Michael       Smith        United States    Virginia
Michelle      Gibson       United States    New Jersey
Jim           Siegle       United States    Oregon
Anna          Harris       United States    Ohio
```

So I didnt want to manually track these in excel one by one because in reality it has 5,000 rows and 36 columns. is there a way like connect an ETL tool to SharePoint 365 or maybe a trick to update the columns and rows that only needs to get changes or update?

Or do I have to erase the whole contents of the list and then upload the new sets? Like truncate the whole list then insert a new batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SSIS, so I only answer the question stand in the perspective of Excel and SharePoint.

1. Create a document library and upload your excel to the library. Change or update the content online.
2. Create an workflow for the document library, while the excel file is changed, the workflow will start. Then this workflow will update the content to the SharePoint List you have created.

   If you can use the Visual Studio Workflow, you can filter the changed data and update the corresponding records in SharePoint list. If you don't have VS/C# basic, you can use the SharePoint Designer to design the workflow, but iterate over the excel with 5,000 rows may encounter unpredictable problems(But this is the simple way for none-developer).

Official [workflow resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/get-started-with-workflows-in-sharepoint) for you.

Comment: Do these apply or work in SharePoint 365. Does the features of Visual Studio Workflow have something in common like powerapps?

Comment: Yes, it works well for SharePoint online. Visual Studio Workflow is  more powerful than SharePoint  Designer, it is fit for professional developers. Currently there are no pure Powerapps style's VS workflow.

Comment: Hi Seiya, when you said "while the excel file is changed, the workflow will start. Then this workflow will update the content to the SharePoint List you have created" did you mean that the document library acts like a storage? but users are allowed to make changes in this document library then the workflow reflects all changes in the sharepoint list that acts like the front end report?

Comment: Yes, the document library acts as a storage. The list like the front end report but not all the same

Comment: Thank you I will apply what you suggested